# Scala throws an exception when I try to launch it on ubuntu

Tags: java, scala, exception

I am trying to launch scala on `Ubuntu 16.04.3`. I installed java and scala but when I type scala in the terminal, all of a sudden it throws an exception.

---

## Step 1: Installating Java and Scala

First, I Installed Java by following these steps described in [How to install java](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04):

```
 - $sudo apt-get update
 - $sudo apt-get install default-jre
 - $sudo apt-get install default-jdk
 - $sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
 - $sudo apt-get update
 - $sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

When I type `$java -version` I get:

```
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

Second, I installed scala by using the following command `$sudo apt-get install scala`

---

## Step 2: Running scala

From the console when I type `$scala` I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/script/Compilable
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.createInterpreter(ILoop.scala:126)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:908)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:906)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:906)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:906)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:74)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Comment: I'll try it now @GhostCat sorry I didn't check it later in the day

Comment: @GhostCat sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there are various issues with Scala in combination with Java9 
( see [here](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10603) for example ).

The upcoming release Scala [2.12.4](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3587) is supposed to fix some of these.

At this point in time, the "best" option is probably to *not* install Java9, but to go with Java8. See [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/) for guidance how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_151).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>